# Commons Collections 4 Maven REPO

Tags: maven, dependencies

Hi i need apache's commons-collections 4, because of its more generic functions.

I had this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

But for a while it disappeared in the mven repositories.

Does anaybody know where i can find it again for maven?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```